# Windows7: Startup Repair

Tags: windows, dual-boot, ntfs

Next to my Linux environment I've installed a Windows7 system. I am no longer able to boot the windows system as it does directly start the so called "System Repair" which (should) check the system drive. After 10+ hours it was still running, so I thought I try to fix this via linux...

I can still mount all windows drives without trouble, so they are probably not damaged (?)

Does anyone know how to dissable the "Startup Repair" from Linux?

---

*yes I know, this is maybe a bit off-topic, but AFAIK there is no better StackExchange Site for this?*

Comment: @Christopher is it possible to move it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Boot Repair Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)? I've found it quite useful when dealing with boot issues of Windows/Linux dual boot setups.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow